# Javascript function for changing the text and glyphicon of <h4>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header for some list elements. The list elements are stored in a div container. When clicking on the header the div container is either shown or not.

Here is the Code :

```
<div class="list-group">
<h4 id="header4"class="list-group-item-heading glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down PruefinhalteHeader" onclick="javascript:show('divPruefinhalte'); return false">@Html.DisplayName("Prüfinhalte")</h4>
<div class="list-group" id="divPruefinhalte">
    @foreach (var item in Model.SelectedContentsToCheckNames)
    {
        <p class="list-group-item">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item)
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

And this is the function for fading in and out:

```
    function show(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var mydiv = document.getElementById(id);
        mydiv.style.display = (mydiv.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
    }
}
```

How can I change the glyphicon in  with id ="header4" from "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" to "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"by clicking on the header?

Comment: If you use jQuery, you might be able to do something like `$('#` + id).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')` and on the next row `$('#` + id).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up')`

Comment: Thanks, that works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `classList` to change the classes on an element. Also note that you don't need the feature check for `getElementById` - it has been a guaranteed feature of all browsers for decades. Here's a complete example:

```
function show(id) {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById(id);
  mydiv.style.display = (mydiv.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
  document.getElementById('header4').classList.remove('glyphicon-chevron-down').add('glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
```

Here's the same in jQuery:

```
function show(id) {
  $('#' + id).toggle();
  $('#header4').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
}
```

Comment: Man you are Incredible! Thank you very much :) It work´s!